# AWS Glue convert files from JSON to Parquet with same partitions as source table

Tags: amazon-web-services, bigdata, aws-glue

We are using AWS glue to convert JSON files stored in our S3 datalake.

Here are the steps that I followed,

1. Created a crawler for generating table on Glue from our datalake 
   bucket which has JSON data.
2. The newly created tables have partitions as follows,

   Name, Year, Month, day, hour
3. Created a glue job to convert it to Parquet and store in a different bucket

With these process, the jobs run successfully but the data in the new bucket is not partitioned. Its just comes under a single directory.

What I want to achieve is the converted parquet files should get the same partitions as in the source table/data lake bucket.

Also, i want to increase the file size of the parquet files(reduce the number of files).

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Can you please add your `write-dynamic-frame` code to your question and the path(s) within your bucket for the resulting files.  Have you tried the example code from [Managing Partitions for ETL Output in AWS Glue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-partitions.html#aws-glue-programming-etl-partitions-writing)?

Answer (score 3):

Try the below for writing the dynamic frame.

```
glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
frame=<output_dataframe>,
connection_type="s3",
connection_options={"path": "s3://<output_bucket_path>",
                    "partitionKeys": ["Name", "Year", "Month" , "day", "hour"]},
format="parquet")
```